# Event dispatcher

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flex3

I have two classes and i tried **event dispatch** from one class to other class. Here i have used button to invoke the class. But dispatch not working.

```
class name cusDispatcher.as
 package
```

{

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import Globe;


public  class CusDispatcher extends EventDispatcher
{


    public function CusDispatcher():void
    {


        Globe.self.realstage.btn_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, 
    doAction);


    }
    public function doAction(event:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        dispatchEvent(new Event('myevent'));

      }

  }

}
```

class name EventDispatcherExample.as
    package
  {

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
import Globe;

public class EventDispatcherExample extends EventDispatcher
{


    public function EventDispatcherExample(Mc:MovieClip) 
    {
            Globe.self.realstage = Mc;
            var start:CusDispatcher = new CusDispatcher();

            Globe.self.realstage.addEventListener('myevent', handler);
            trace("one");

    }

    public function handler(event:Event):void
    {
        trace("My Event");


    }
 }
 }
```

In the adobe CC i used this instance to run the class

```
var Call:EventDispatcherExample = new EventDispatcherExample(this);
```

Whenever i click the button(btn_mc) in the adobe flash cc it does not show any 
 trace of dispatch event.So could please analyze and give solution for this one.

Comment: Because **Globe.self.realstage** does not dispatch **myevent** event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your other click listener (in the EventDispatcherExample) working?

The problem might be that you have declared your CusDispatcher as a local variable within a function

```
var start:CusDispatcher = new CusDispatcher();
```

Once the function is complete these variables are cleaned up. Try to declare it at the beginning of your class as a class variable:

```
private var start:CusDispatcher;

public function EventDispatcherExample(Mc:MovieClip)...
```

and then assign your new Dispatcher to it

```
start = new CusDispatcher();
```